# ¿A qué se debe que onSelectedDayChange de Android retorne el valor del mes restándole uno?

Tags: android, date

Estoy recuperando la fecha que ha sido seleccionada en un `CalendarView` con este código:

```
    final CalendarView simpleCalendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    simpleCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(String.format("%04d", year));
                sb.append(String.format("%02d", month + 1));
                sb.append(String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth));
                strFecha=sb.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "Día: " + dayOfMonth + " Mes: " + month + " Año: " + year);
        }
    });
```

Pero resulta que **me está dando el valor del mes restándole 1**.

Si presiono alguna fecha del mes de `Enero` me muestra esto en el Log:

```
D/CalendarioActivity: Día: 2 Mes: 0 Año: 2018
```

Y si es una fecha de `Febrero`:

```
D/CalendarioActivity: Día: 5 Mes: 1 Año: 2018
```

Lo estoy resolviendo sumándole `1` al mes, pero me parece algo muy extraño. ¿A qué se debe este comportamiento? ¿El hecho de sumarle 1 podría traerme problemas en el futuro?

Comment: No es que sea un error, si no que esta implementado de esa manera. Muchas cosas en programación se comienzan a contar desde cero, como las listas o los arreglos.

Comment: @DavidMinaya lo de los arrays sí me consta, pero ignoraba que con los meses aplicasen ese principio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increible como lo aparezca, [los meses en Java esta en base a 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH):

Cita de la documentacion:

> Número de campo para get y set que indica el mes. Este es un valor
>   específico del calendario. El primer mes del año es ENERO, que es 0;
>   el último depende de la cantidad de meses en un año.

Es un comportamiento que no cambiara por lo que no, no te traerá ningún problema en el futuro.

Pudieras utilizas la clase [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) que fue introducida para "reparar" ese error:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(year,month,dayOfMonth));
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Tambien existen librerías externas que corrigen y agregan muchas funcionalidades como [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: En efecto, no ha cambiado en **[Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)**. Me fui un poco más adelante porque tu enlace era algo anciano :)

Comment: Pudieras comentarme el enlace que encontraste? Asi tener la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Está en el comentario de arriba, donde dice **Java 9**. Y **[también aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY)**.

Comment: No me habia fijado que yo estaba dando referencia a la version 1.5 de java.  Link actualizado.